# TCP congestion control Windows 7

Tags: windows, tcp, tcpip, network-protocols

Based on what I read, Compound TCP is disabled by default in Windows 7. If so, which default congestion control algorithm does windows 7 use? Is it TCP RENO or NEW RENO? Could you give me some links as references please.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this question: [Windows TCP Congestion Control](http://serverfault.com/questions/236913/windows-tcp-congestion-control)?

Comment: Hi @jamie. Welcome to SU. What have you done to try to find the answer? I'm no expert, but is this something that can be found on google? If you provide details of what you've found so far you're more likely to get help here

Comment: @beatcracker: Yes, I have looked at that question. My question is an extension to that one. More specifically asking what does it mean when it says the following in netsh 'none: Use the built-in standard congestion control algorithm.'. Is Windows using one of the popular congestion controls or something which is theirs and not known about otherwise.

Comment: @CallumDA33: I have tried searching the web and trying to find it from research papers as well. The most relevant thing that I have found so far is [link](http://caia.swin.edu.au/reports/140516A/CAIA-TR-140516A.pdf). Which says Windows' default congestion control, but there seem to be no details on the actual algorithm anywhere.

Comment: I managed to find a reference [link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6289279&tag=1) which says that TCP Reno is the standard one on Windows. However would be great if I can know more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is an extension to that one. More specifically asking what
>   does it mean when it says the following in netsh 'none: Use the
>   built-in standard congestion control algorithm.'. Is Windows using one
>   of the popular congestion controls or something which is theirs and
>   not known about otherwise

Probably it's some variation of [Reno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion-avoidance_algorithm#TCP_Tahoe_and_Reno). [This paper](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=70189) mentions it:

> In this paper, we propose a novel Compound TCP (CTCP) approach, which
>   is a synergy of delay-based and loss-based approach. In CTCP, we add a
>   scalable delay-based component into the standard TCP Reno congestion
>   avoidance algorithm (i.e., the loss-based component).

Here is another relevant quote from [CS/EE 143 Communication Networks course](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs143/Project/NetworkSimGuidelines-2014.pdf):

> Microsoft writes its own congestion control algorithm, while modern
>   Linux kernels default to an algorithm called CUBIC TCP.